# google maps zoom bounds

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I have function to show map on my website. It works well for desktop version, but does not on mobile. It does not affect nor bounds nor zoom level. Map is centered somewhere...

```
services_vars.search_lat = ''
services_vars.search_lng = ''
parseInt(services_vars.zoom) = 14

if($('#mapView').length > 0) {
    var propsAjaxURL = services_vars.admin_url + 'admin-ajax.php';
    var propsSecurity = $('#securityAppMap').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: propsAjaxURL,
        data: {
            'action': 'reales_get_searched_properties',
            'country': services_vars.search_country,
            'state': services_vars.search_state,
            'city': services_vars.search_city,
            'category': services_vars.search_category,
            'type': services_vars.search_type,
            'min_price': services_vars.search_min_price,
            'max_price': services_vars.search_max_price,
            'bedrooms' : services_vars.search_bedrooms,
            'bathrooms' : services_vars.search_bathrooms,
            'neighborhood' : services_vars.search_neighborhood,
            'min_area' : services_vars.search_min_area,
            'max_area' : services_vars.search_max_area,
            'amenities': services_vars.search_amenities,
            'page': services_vars.page,
            'sort': services_vars.sort,
            'security': propsSecurity
        },
        success: function(data) {
            appMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapView'), options);
            var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {
                name : 'Styled'
            });
            appMap.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);
            appMap.getStreetView().setOptions(panoramaOptions);

            var searchedPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(services_vars.search_lat, services_vars.search_lng);
            appMap.setCenter(searchedPosition);
            appMap.setZoom(parseInt(services_vars.zoom));

            if(data.getprops === true) {
                addMarkers(data.props, appMap);

                appMap.fitBounds(markers.reduce(function(bounds, marker) {
                    return bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
                }, new google.maps.LatLngBounds()));

                google.maps.event.trigger(appMap, 'resize');

            }
        },
        error: function(errorThrown) {

        }
    });
}
```